# How to return "string" after changing it's text properties?

Tags: string, text-properties

When using the `propertize` function alone on an entire string, it works. How to return a string, after changing its different sections separately with  `add-face-text-property` (probably later repeatedly on different sections)?

```el
(let ((heading "Heading [50%] [1/2]"))
  (concat
   "..."
   (when heading
     ;;  (propertize heading 'face 'header-line)
     (set-text-properties 0 (length heading) '(face header-line) heading)
     (add-face-text-property
      (string-match "\\(\\(\\[[0-9]*%\\]\\)\\|\\(\\[[0-9]*/[0-9]*\\]\\)\\)" heading 0)
      (match-end 0)
      `(:foreground ,(face-foreground (org-get-todo-face keyword) nil 1))
      nil
      heading))))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an extremely basic question about Emacs Lisp, and it has nothing to do with strings or `add-face-text-property` specifically. You really should read through the [Emacs Lisp Intro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html), which is a manual that teaches how to program in Emacs Lisp. It does not assume any prior knowledge of programming.

In Lisp, “returning” a value really means that the expression evaluates to that value. The code you pasted in your question has a lot of irrelevant details in it, and some mistakes. Let’s assume you have this code instead:

```lisp
(let ((heading "some string"))
  (modify-string heading)
  (modify-string heading))
```

`modify-string` here represents any function which has side effects that modify the contents of the string we pass in. Currently this expression evaluates to `nil`, because the last thing it does is call `modify-string`, and `modify-string` returns nil. Essentially, this code starts with a string, modifies it twice, and then throws it away. How can we return the string instead? We need to add another expression to the body that will evaluate to the modified string. What is the simplest expression that evaluates to that string? Yes, the variable itself:

```lisp
(let ((heading "some string"))
  (modify-string heading)
  (modify-string heading)
  heading)
```

This is not an uncommon pattern; you’ll see it fairly frequently in the Emacs Lisp code that you read.

Comment: Thanks ! Could this uncommon pattern be changed inside this "when" block using same text property functions or not ? Any keywords?

Comment: OP: If you have another question, post it as another question. Comments are not for extended discussion, including Q&A.